# Set payment code to new payment method created

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I have created a payment method based on this tutorial:

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/2361-2/

But, when I get the payment code it is set to **checkmo**.
Anyone can help me on how to set my own distinct code for this method?

Regards,
Gustavo

Comment: In this file which code you set : app/code/local/[name_space]/[your_module]/Model ?

Comment: Hey Dhiren, I used the following line based on the tutorial:     protected $_code = 'pagamentoparceiros';

Comment: I also set:     protected $_isOffline = true;